# Update cell with JSON array index 0 or with sub-string

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a JSON array in a cell and I need to update that cell by removing the second item in the array. Or, if you consider it as a string, I need to update the cell by removing part of the string. For example:

**Original**

```
[{"ID":1}, {"ID":2}]
```

**Update**

```
[{"ID":1}]
```

**Table**

[image]

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: It should be 2014

Comment: JSON support is not available in SQL Server 2014, so you need to use a string-based approach. Does the JSON array always have two items?

Comment: In my case the JSON array have only two itams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not on 2016+, you can do a bit of string manipulation.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Column1] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'[{"ID":1}, {"ID":2}]')
,(2,'[{"ID":2}]') 

Select * 
      ,NewValue = replace(left(Column1,charindex(',',Column1+',')-1)+']',']]',']')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Column1                 NewValue
1   [{"ID":1}, {"ID":2}]    [{"ID":1}]
2   [{"ID":2}]              [{"ID":2}]
```

Comment: Thanks but that was just an example, the actually array items is a bit longer.

Comment: @Dino Perhaps you should provide a more representative sample.   Again, since you are not on 2016+ you will be stuck with string manipulation or temporarily  convert  the JSON to XML for processing.

Comment: I will update with an example closer to the actually one, I am ok with string manipulation since would be not easy to change the SQL Server.